# Android Intent's Stack - Login Screen and Main Menu

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, flags

When I have two activities

```
Activity A, B;
// A stands for Login Screen
// B stands for Main Application Screen
```

Application starts with `A`, then user performs login and he will be pointed to `B`

When I launch `B` I add this flag to Intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but when I finish the `B` I expect it to be the last activity and to quit the application.

Instead of what I expected, `A` is brought to front, and user stills on Login Screen again.

Should I start `A` from `B` as `startActivityForResult` and use `B` as main activity of whole application ?

Or the flag is not working as it should be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't bother with intent flags. When activity A starts activity B after a successful login, just have A call `finish()`.

An alternative, slightly more involved, approach is to make B your main activity and in B's `onCreate` method, start activity A for a result, which should be some pass/fail flag. When Activity A finishes (either on a successful login, failure, or the user just quitting), activity B determines in `onActivityResult` whether to continue or to finish, based on the returned value. This works because, according to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity.

Answer (score 3):

Use finish method:

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent();
lIntent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(lIntent);
finish();
```